# Capybara and formaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

I have a simple form with a single 'email' field and two submit buttons.

The first button 'Next' triggers the forms default action: '/login'.
The second button 'Reset Password' has a 'formaction' element that redirect the form to a new destination: '/reset_password'.

```
<button type="submit" name="login_button">Next</button>
<button class="secondary_button" type="submit" name="reset_button" formaction="/reset_password">Reset Password</button>
```

The form works perfectly well, however when testing with Capybara:

```
click_button "Reset Password"
```

it triggers the form's default action and not the correct action. I've confirmed the default action is being triggered with:

```
save_and_show_page
```

It's definitely triggering the correct button but seems to be ignoring the 'formaction'.

Any ideas?

Comment: same here, we still have to wait for that...

Answer (score 0):

as you probably know, that's an HTML5 attribute, since Capybara uses RackTtest  by default as its driver/browser (which is a very barebones, no JS support driver), it might just not be seeing it at all. I would assume you need a setup with a headless browser like PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/index.html). Which supports HTML5 attributes.